# HL Fabric 2.0, external chaincode launcher: error in simulation: failed to execute transaction: could not launch chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I try to deploy Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 to OpenShift. By now, I'm using minishift with virtualbox on macOS for a local cluster.
I make of use the deploCC.sh script from fabric-samples/test-network. Unfortunately, the function `chaincodeInvokeInit` fails with the following error. Until then, everything works as expected.
I set up an external chaincode builder and launcher which should run the chaincode inside the peer container without starting a chaincode container. I verified my external chaincode builder in the test-network. Further, I checked, that the chaincode build is located at the peer in `/var/hyperledger/production/externalbuilder/builds/`

```
2020-03-10 12:14:19.291 CET [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> DEBU 042 ESCC invoke result: response:<status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 5f25a0aacbf70ba3dc80b203ab4dcf01561784f9a00166a4917ba1cb9202bbf9: could not launch chaincode fabcar_3:9629a4f04de8c0ec0fa1c11b1996355800c7b5687867fb898bce3164a8fd3cec: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0" > 
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 5f25a0aacbf70ba3dc80b203ab4dcf01561784f9a00166a4917ba1cb9202bbf9: could not launch chaincode fabcar_3:9629a4f04de8c0ec0fa1c11b1996355800c7b5687867fb898bce3164a8fd3cec: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0" 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Invoke execution on org1.peer0 org2.peer0 failed  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

command terminated with exit code 1
```

I’d appreciate your help and/or ideas.
Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Hi Polem, I could solve the problem but I'm not exactly sure anymore in what problem I ran. I posted an article on Medium about how to set up the external chaincode builder and launcher in HL Fabric 2.0. You could follow the tutorial and see if it works for you. If not, I'll have a deeper look at the problem again.
https://medium.com/@robinklemens/setting-up-the-external-chaincode-builder-and-launcher-in-hyperledger-fabric-2-0-b17f43a3d8ed

Answer (score 0):

There might be bugs in your chaincodes. You should debug them in native environment before adding the code to your chaincodes.

For example, this GO code snippet will give you an error `assignment to entry in nil map`, but will prompt you `error in simulation: failed to execute transaction` if you deploy it as a chaincode and it is run by a peer.

```
var m map[string]int // Not initialised with m := make(map[string]int)
m["pi"] = 3.14
```